Is there a way to pack scip into a self-contained, single executable program?
My server network connection is restricted so I want to compile locally and then upload to the server. But apparently scip has many dependencies, so I tried to pack it into an .AppImage file with linuxdeploy. However linuxdeploy throws error on calling strip on almost every copied libraries:
Calling strip on library AppDir/usr/lib/libblas.so.3
ERROR: Strip call failed: /tmp/.mount_linux/usr/bin/strip: AppDir/usr/lib/libblas.so.3: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn`
/tmp/.mount_linux/usr/bin/strip: Unable to recognize the format of the input file `AppDir/usr/lib/libblas.so.3`

how can I fix this, or are there some compile options I can add/modify to bundle the scip?
